# Create a multiplication table as a multidimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, arguments

I am trying to create a function which returns a multiplication table as a two-dimensional array, when passed the dimensions of that multiplication table as the arguments of the function.

For example:

```
multiplicationTable(2, 2); //returns [[1, 2], [2, 4]]
multiplicationTable(3, 4); //returns [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 6, 8,], [3, 6, 9, 14]]
```

I am fundamentally trying to understand how to create a multidimensional array of which the properties of each dimension are determined by the given variables. Any explanation of the processes used would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Seems like you need to use nested for loops...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think that you have an error in the second example, the last number must be 12 instead 14

You need to create a `loop` nested inside another `loop`, look at the next code:

```
function multiplicationTable(groups, indexes){

  var array = [];
  var g;
  var i;

  //---Loop for the groups
  for(g = 0; g < groups; g++){

    //---Create multidimensional array
    array[g] = [];

    //---Loop for the indexes of the each group
    for(i = 0; i < indexes; i++){

      array[g][i] = (g + 1) * (i + 1);

    }

  }

  return array;

}
```

Then you can call the function:

```
multiplicationTable(2, 2);
//  [[1,2],[2,4]]

multiplicationTable(3, 4);
//  [[1,2,3,4],[2,4,6,8],[3,6,9,12]]
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/o1u7dm5x/)